# How do I restore an accidentally deleted initrd image?

Tags: kernel

I accidentally deleted the initrd image on my system.  How do I restore it?

Answer (score 6):

This is the answer to the original question, how to extract the initrd.lz from the live CD, typically used if you are making a custom live CD.

copy the initrd.lz to a working directory ( `~`)

```
cp /media/cdrom/initrd.lz ~
```

Make a directory to extract the contents to, I will use `initrd`, cd into the directory

```
mkdir ~/initrd
cd ~/initrd
```

Extract

```
lzma -dc -S .lz ../initrd.lz | cpio -imvd --no-absolute-filenames
```

Make any changes you might need, re-package

```
cd ~/initrd
find . | cpio --quiet --dereference -o -H newc | lzma -7 > ../cusotm.initrd.lz
```

Your new initrd will be in your home directory and called `cusotm.initrd.lz`

Comment: But how do I make it `initrd.img` like `initrd.img-3.2.0-15-generic-pae`?

Comment: I'm trying to use initrd from a livecd on my ubuntu install. Deleted it accidently.

Comment: Well, that is the hard way ;) use `mkinitramfs`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen but how to repack this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/777260/how-to-repack-initrd-img ?

Answer (score 5):

The initrd image for each kernel is built at kernel installation time from the modules and applications on the machine.  You can simply build a missing initrd using the command below:

```
update-initramfs -c -k <version>
```

(Do remember to subsitute in the appropriate version for your kernel.)

Comment: when there is no existing initrd, the verbose of this command is nothing to be done (13.10)

Answer (score 4):

This is a better way to solve the OP problem posted in the comments.

> I'm trying to use initrd from a livecd on my ubuntu install. Deleted it accidently. – Binoy Babu

To make an initramfs, first boot an alternate kernel (older is fine).

Then run

```
sudo mkinitramfs 3.2.0-15-generic-pae -o /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-15-generic-pae
```

I do not have the pae kernel installed, if "3.2.0-15-generic-pae" does not work, list the contents of `/lib/modules` to get the name:

```
ls /lib/modules
```

If you do not have an older kernel, you can boot a live CD and use `chroot`:

1. Mount your root partition first: `mount -t ext4 /dev/sdX /mnt`. Make sure you use the correct partition name and type in this command. Use commands like `lsblk`, `blkid` etc. to find the correct partition.
2. [Optional] If you have a separate boot partition mount that next: `mount -t ext4 /dev/sdY /mnt/boot`
3. Next bind mount all the virtual file systems needed by the `mkinitramfs` command...
   mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
   mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
   mount --bind /dev /dev/proc
4. Now switch to the `/mnt` folder and run the `mkinitramfs` command as described above.

Comment: This answer saved my bacon!