# How to repack initrd.img?

Tags: initramfs

On original /boot/initrd.img-*kernel_ver* `binwalk` shows this structure:

[image]

From **0** to **22528** bytes there is CPIO archive contains only GenuineIntel.bin firmware in specific folder hierarchy.
From **22528** bytes there is gzip archiwe contains appropriate file system and this gzip is also archived with CPIO

After unpacking and modifying how can I compress initrd.img in the same way (with the same folder hierarchy) ? like this original structure:

[image]

After suggestion from comment :

```
find . | cpio --quiet --dereference -o -H newc | lzma -7 > ../cusotm.initrd.lz
```

`binwalk` :

[image]

This is completly different structure.

Comment: You extract the initrd.img into a working directory. You add your GenuineIntel.bin firmware in specific folder hierarchy to the working directory. You then remake the archive with `find  . | cpio --quiet --dereference -o -H newc | lzma -7 > ../cusotm.initrd.lz` If that procedure is not working , clarify what commands you ran and what is not working.

Comment: Your edit, with a picture, adds little to nothing of my understanding of your problem. You need to extract the image, add in your code, with the appropriate file structure and location of GenuineIntel.bin firmware and re-package into a new .img.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen as I said this made different file...

Comment: @bodhi.zazen do you finally understand what I am asking ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen "no" ? :) what is wrong with you ? Is your high reputation some kind of fiction ? ;) I have done exactly what you said (and what you are saying now) and result is in modified question. Sometimes its better to say "I don't know" - than writing useless impertinence about archiving and compression ;)

Comment: It looks like the initramfs file is a concatenation of CPIO archives. Each CPIO archive can be compressed (with gzip, xz etc.) or uncompressed.  Your input file starts with an uncompressed one at offset 0, then it continues with a compressed one at offset 22528. Unfortunately I don't know of a standard tool which can extract a concatenation of maybe-compressed CPIO archives.

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out how to make exactly the same `initrd.img` archive.

Bodhi.zazen answer will probably work because this is commonly known solution:

```
find . | cpio --quiet --dereference -o -H newc | lzma -7 > ../cusotm.initrd.lz
```

but the question was different. This answer would be good if in cpio archive there is one gzipped file system but in this situation there is also Intel firmware in specific folder structure which I want to keep.

#### To keep the same folder hierarchy three steps are needed:

> 1. Make **CPIO** file system archive with simple -o option without **newc** format in created before eg. base folder:
>
>    `find . | cpio -o | gzip -9  > ../base/file_system.gz`
> 2. Make proper archive with **newc** format containing *kernel/x86/microcode/GenuineIntel.bin*:
>
>    `find kernel/ | cpio -o -H newc > new_initrd.img`
> 3. Add gzipped filesystem archive to the proper new_initrd.img:
>
>    `find base/ | cpio -o >> new_initrd.img`

Comment: Great! Thanks! +10! But how do you unpack original initrd?

Comment: Also, your solution creates a bit different structure. I've got the absolutely the same tructure in binwalk when I did the step (2) first and then `find . | cpio -o | gzip -9  >> new_initrd.img`

Comment: @EdiD how do you unpack original initrd?

Comment: @ImranRazaKhan you need four steps: `cpio -id < initrd.img-kernel_ver` ; `dd if=initrd.img-4.4.0-22-generic of=image.gz bs=22528 skip=1` -match your initrd.img file name and block size;  `gunzip image.gz`; `cpio -i < image`

Answer (score 5):

I recently ran into this same question and my web searching led me to this thread, so in case it helps others following in those footsteps, here's a 2018 answer to an old question...

It seems in "recent" kernels the initrd.img file can contain an uncompressed cpio archive (i.e. containing microcode updates) prepended to the (compressed) cpio archive containing the normal initramfs directory tree.

This is discussed briefly in the Debian Wiki page:
    https://wiki.debian.org/initramfs#How_to_inspect_initramfs
, but more precise code for parsing through this sort of initrd.img file can be found in the `splitinitramfs()` function within the `unmkinitramfs` command found in the `initramfs-tools-core` package (e.g.
https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/tree/unmkinitramfs
).

I have not tried to rebuild this sort of initrd.img file myself, but based on that Wiki page it seems that to edit the initramfs boot scripts, one would not want to unpack the GenuineIntel archive at all.  Instead, you could just preserve that cpio archive as-is somewhere separately, then unpack the second (compressed) archive, modify the directory tree, and rebuild the compressed cpio archive, then concatenate the saved microcode archive with the newly-generated one.

(The code that originally generated this "prepended" archive is found in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/intel_microcode`.)

Answer (score 4):

You repackage with

```
cd your_working_directory_with_modifications
find . | cpio --quiet --dereference -o -H newc | lzma -7 > ../cusotm.initrd.lz
```

The second command renames the initrd, you specifiy the initrd to use when booting in grub.

I suggest you test (boot)the custom initrd before moving or renaming it.

*Additional information from the discussion in the comments:*

First I do not think you are understanding the role of cpio / tar. both cpio and tar take a number of files and/or directories and make them into one file or archive.

Second I do not think you understand the role of compression, compression simply makes the resulting archive smaller. You can use any tool you wish for compression.

See

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomizeLiveInitrd

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Initramfs/Guide

Third, the linux kernel uses cipo rather then tar.

See

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt

See the "Why cpio rather than tar?" section

> ### Why cpio rather than tar?
>
> This decision was made back in December, 2001.  The discussion started
>   here:
>
> http://www.uwsg.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0112.2/1538.html
>
> And spawned a second thread (specifically on tar vs cpio), starting
>   here:
>
> http://www.uwsg.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0112.2/1587.html
>
> The quick and dirty summary version (which is no substitute for
>   reading the above threads) is:
>
> 1) cpio is a standard.  It's decades old (from the AT&T days), and
>   already    widely used on Linux (inside RPM, Red Hat's device driver
>   disks).  Here's    a Linux Journal article about it from 1996:
>
> ```
>   http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1213
> ```
>
> It's not as popular as tar because the traditional cpio command
>   line tools    require _truly_hideous_ command line arguments.  But
>   that says nothing    either way about the archive format, and there
>   are alternative tools,    such as:
>
> ```
>  http://freecode.com/projects/afio
> ```
>
> 2) The cpio archive format chosen by the kernel is simpler and cleaner
>   (and    thus easier to create and parse) than any of the (literally
>   dozens of)    various tar archive formats.  The complete initramfs
>   archive format is    explained in buffer-format.txt, created in
>   usr/gen_init_cpio.c, and    extracted in init/initramfs.c.  All three
>   together come to less than 26k    total of human-readable text.
>
> 3) The GNU project standardizing on tar is approximately as relevant
>   as    Windows standardizing on zip.  Linux is not part of either, and
>   is free    to make its own technical decisions.
>
> 4) Since this is a kernel internal format, it could easily have been
>   something brand new.  The kernel provides its own tools to create and 
>   extract this format anyway.  Using an existing standard was
>   preferable,    but not essential.
>
> 5) Al Viro made the decision (quote: "tar is ugly as hell and not
>   going to be    supported on the kernel side"):
>
> ```
>   http://www.uwsg.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0112.2/1540.html
> ```
>
> explained his reasoning:
>
> ```
>   http://www.uwsg.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0112.2/1550.html
>   http://www.uwsg.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0112.2/1638.html
> ```
>
> and, most importantly, designed and implemented the initramfs code.

Comment: This will not preserve folder structure. I want the same structure as original initrd.img. Meaning -> GenuineIntel.bin not compressed just archived with cpio on root in kernel/x86/microcode folder and why lzma while I'm talking about gzip ?

Comment: lzma gives a smaller archive. use gzip if you wish. I am not sure why you are concerned about compression or not, should work just fine with compression and result in a smaller image on the disk. Not really sure what you are trying to accomplish from what you posted.

Comment: I want to know how was it originally done. Probably intel firmware is not compressed because of faster accessibility.

Comment: almost certainly was compressed, you can check the archive. Compression is used by default as it does not noticeably affect performance.

Comment: There isn't anything in cpio manual about compression. Check accepted answer: http://superuser.com/questions/343915/tar-vs-cpio-what-is-the-difference

Comment: I do not think you are understanding what cpio / tar do - "tar and cpio have essentially the same function, which is to create a single contiguous file from an input of multiple files and directories" . The resulting file is then compressed with gzip, lzma, or whatever tool you want. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomizeLiveInitrd

Comment: cpio is used as it is built into the kernel (rather then tar) see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt see the "
Why cpio rather than tar?" section.

Comment: No this is wrong. Tar and cpio are only archivers without any compression. If you want compression you have to use gzip, 7zip, lzma, etc...(thats why it is piped to gzip) and yes I know that cpio is built into kernel

Comment: What is "wrong"?

Comment: and after your edit this is still not answering on my question how to make the same initrd.img file ?

Comment: make a backup `cp old_img old_img.bak` make a new img `find . | cpio --quiet --dereference -o -H newc | lzma -7 > your_new_img_what_ever_name_you_want_to_give_it`

Comment: :) and what is different in this ? comparing to answer ? ok I will edit my question just for clarity

Comment: @EdiD - You are sort of meandering all over the place from the definition / use of cpio / tar to compression affcting kernel performance to stating that the answer is "wrong" and restating the same "wrong" information. Perhaps you need to clarify your question and tell us what commands you ran to what your problem is.

Comment: If it is meandering for you just leave it and go away :) I think we are all in here to learn  more about (this) system ... aren't we ?

Comment: Question was clear from beginning but 'copy and paste' old solution from different question doesn't solve this

Answer (score 1):

in Ubuntu the `initrd.img` is compressed in gzip, I would like to preserve this when I edit it. this is how:

extract:

```
zcat /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-80-generic | cpio --extract
```

compress:

```
find . 2>/dev/null | cpio --quiet --dereference -o -H newc | gzip -9 > /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-80-generic
```

Comment: Hmmm it looks like it works, but it actually will no longer boot my machine. I also noticed that the re-packed archive is significantly bigger than the original one, despite the repack using higher compression (-9). Need to get to the bottom.

Comment: @nisc As far as I recall, that was the only combination worked and with boot. Maybe what's missing is a file permission set. Or theres differences between Ubuntu versions (I've used at the time 14,04)

Comment: The different file size is probably due to --dereference but haven't confirmed/tested it