# How can I show owner information on the encrypted disk lock screen?

Tags: encryption

I have full disk encryption enabled on my laptop's hard drive.

Is there any way to show owner information on the screen where you enter your encrypted disk password upon boot?

Comment: You would have to modify the initramfs and add a custom script or image

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/777260/how-to-repack-initrd-img and http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/initramfs/ Find and modify the image or script